# JAVA: Check if a string ends with a certain pattern using REGEX

Tags: java, string

I have an array of Strings in **Java** like :

```
["stringWithNoSuffix", "secondString", "stringWithSuffix01", "stringWithSuffix99", "stringWithSuffix8notCounted"]
```

I want to get all the strings in my array that end with *"WithSuffix" and a number*.

**E.g:** WithSuffix1, WithSuffix22, WithSuffix09, ... etc

My output then should be :

```
["stringWithSuffix01", "stringWithSuffix99"]
```

The String **"stringWithSuffix8notCounted"** is not counted because it does not end with *"WithSuffix" and a number*.

I can do this with `.contains()` or `.endsWith()` and some conditions but I want to use a regex if possible.
I am pretty newbie with Regular Expressions so that's the reason why I am here asking.

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression: `WithSuffix\d+$`

Explanation:

- the "WithSuffix" is the text you want, nothing special
- `\d` means a digit
- `+` means 1 or more of the previous thingie, here the `\d`
- `$` means end of the input

Because `\` escapes special characters in Java strings, you must escape it with another `\`.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class WithSuffix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> inputs = List.of("stringWithNoSuffix", "secondString", "stringWithSuffix01",
            "stringWithSuffix99", "stringWithSuffix8notCounted");
        List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String i: inputs) {
            if (i.matches(".*WithSuffix\\d+$")) {
                filtered.add(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(filtered);
    }
}
```

Here I added a `.*` (dot means any character, `*` means any number) to ignore any text before the "WithSuffix".